# Create PDF bookmarks Within Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm attempting to build a monthly process that converts an excel file to a PDF **with bookmarks** for each respective sheet.  I'm not seeing a method to successfully create PDF bookmarks from within the Excel workbook. Can this be accomplished without third-party software?

What I've tried:

- Using Header 1 for a cell as well as an entire row.
- Putting Excel Book Mark within the file using a hyperlink reference.
- Adding named range.
- OneDrive [flow Convert File](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/0ffc6d1b79ea481bbbc820df7273f303/convert-a-file-to-pdf-using-onedrive-for-business/)
- Adding a Header.
- Reviewed some VBA Ref libraries hoping to find an `object.bookmark` type approach.

Unfortunately, all attempts have resulted in a PDF file with no bookmarks.

Is there a method to create PDF Bookmarks from Excel? Possibly a VBA ref library that I am unaware of or some front-end trick? Unfortunately, I'm stuck working only with Microsoft tools. Adobe's Excel Add-On does exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Probably a long process: have you thought about building a word document from each sheet and adding your bookmarks then converting to pdf? One approach would be to build a word document template (with all bookmarks) for each sheet linked to your excel worksheet (say through mail merge). Then use vba to open the the template, execute the mail merge and convert to pdf.

Comment: Yeah, that might work, but you're right it might take awhile to build. Thanks for idea.